# How to count no.of Div Elements by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

find the no.of children elements on ".inner" class but without using ".movable" class

```
<div class="inner">
  <div class="movable" id="one">
    <div>one</div>
    <div>Two</div>
    <div>Three</div>
  </div>

  <div class="movable" id="two">
    <div>one</div>
    <div>Two</div>
    <div>Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to find the index of which element?

Comment: #one, #two, #three elements. It is in draggable function

Comment: In future when asking questions can you please provide every detail about what you're looking for to begin with? The edit you've now made invalidates all 6 of the answers this question had previously attracted.

Comment: If you need index you can directly give like that  $("#three").index(); it will return 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$(".inner").children().length;  // direct child
```

or

```
 $(".inner div").length;  // deep child

 $(".inner").find("div").length;    // deep child

 $(".inner > div").length  // direct child
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.inner').children().length
```

Answer (score 1):

---

### Edit: Question was heavily modified. This answer is no longer relevant.

This was the original question:

> I have to find number of `div` elements present in `.inner` class and also find the index of that element:

```html
<div class="inner">
    <div class="movable" id="one"></div>
    <div class="movable" id="two"></div>
    <div class="movable" id="three"></div>
</div>
```

---

jQuery exposes a `length` property on the matches a selector pulls:

```
$('.inner').children().length;
```

The matches `$('.inner').children()` pulls will be held in a jQuery object whose indices are similar to that of an array. `$('.inner').children()[0]` will be your `<div class="movable" id="one"></div>` element, for instance.

### Demo

This demo displays the number of `div` elements contained within your `.inner` element.

```js
var div_count = $('.inner').children().length;

$('#result').text(div_count + " children.");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inner">
  <div class="movable" id="one"></div>
  <div class="movable" id="two"></div>
  <div class="movable" id="three"></div>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Yes. I got length. How to find index of that elements

Comment: @MohaideenIsmail my answer answers the question you originally asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number of child `divs`:

```
$('.inner div').length;
```

If you want the index of a specific child:

```
$('.inner #two').index();
```

Answer (score 0):

Working **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j8vhwwqm/)**

Use following

```
var div_count = $('.inner > div').length;
```